# Having trouble with my dungeons and dragons dice roller

Tags: java, dice

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project2Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfSets = 0;
    System.out.println("How many sets of dice would you like to roll?");
    numberOfSets = kb.nextInt();
    kb.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSets; i++) {
        int dice1 = 0;
        int dice2 = 0;
        int dice3 = 0;
        int dice4 = 0;
        int diceTotal = 0;

        if (dice1 < dice2 && dice1 < dice3 && dice1 < dice4) {
            diceTotal = dice2 + dice3 + dice4;
            System.out.println("Your roll total is " + diceTotal + " and your lowest roll was " + dice1 + ".");
            break;
        } else if (dice2 < dice1 && dice2 < dice3 && dice2 < dice4) {
            diceTotal = dice1 + dice3 + dice4;
            System.out.println("Your roll total is " + diceTotal + " and your lowest roll was " + dice2 + ".");
            break;
        } else if (dice3 < dice1 && dice3 < dice2 && dice3 < dice4) {
            diceTotal = dice1 + dice2 + dice4;
            System.out.println("Your roll total is " + diceTotal + " and your lowest roll was " + dice3 + ".");
            break;
        } else if (dice4 < dice1 && dice4 < dice2 && dice4 < dice3) {
            diceTotal = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;
            System.out.println("Your roll total is " + diceTotal + " and your lowest roll was " + dice4 + ".");
            break;
        }
    }
    kb.close();
}
```

This is my main class. The whole point of this is to take four different rolls of a six sided die, check and see which roll is the lowest, and add the three highest rolls together while telling the user what their lowest roll was.

The main thing I am having trouble with is making a dice class.

I know I need an int to hold the dice value, a constructor to actually create the random integer, and a getter to actually return the random integers to the main class. How can I go about doing this?

Another question: How can I make the user choose a set and reroll the lowest value in that set? What I mean by that is when the user rolls, the three largest dice rolls are added together and the lowest one is put off to the side. The user must be forced to re roll the lowest value of the three highest dice roll even if they do not want to.

The user must be able to put in a number dictating which set will end up being re rolled.

I apologize if this does not make much sense, so if anyone would like to suggest edits to make this more clear, that would be great.

Comment: Did you already try something? I think you should use an array with the different values possible and a getValue that returns a random

Comment: I already have an idea for what I am trying to do with my dice class. I want it to have a constructor and a getter to roll the dice in the dice class and then make it able to return those values to the main class. I also would like to avoid arrays if possible.

Comment: How about a `Dice` class with a `Roll()` method and a constructor that takes the max value possible to roll (6 for 6-sided)?

Comment: Also, your current code won't output anything cuz all the dice are 0 and 0 is never less than 0--you don't roll the "dice" (ints) in any way

Comment: Just FYI, it's 'pseudocode' not 'sudo code'.  I would normally correct that type of thing in an edit, but really the whole first paragraph doesn't pertain to the actual question, and so I would edit the whole thing out if anything.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @soong ! I have made those edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom DiceRoller class that has capability of rolling any number of 4d6-drop-lowest sets.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DiceRoller
{
    private Random rand;

    public DiceRoller()
    {
        this.rand = new Random();
    }

    public int rollSingleDie()
    {
        return rand.nextInt(6)+1;
    }

    public List<Integer> roll4d6DropLowest()
    {
        List<Integer> retList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Add 4 numbers to the list to simulate 4 rolls.
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            retList.add(rollSingleDie());
        }

        // Remove the lowest roll of the 4. 
        retList.remove(Collections.min(retList));

        return retList;
    }

    public List<List<Integer>> rollSets(int numSets)
    {
        List<List<Integer>> results = new List<List<Integer>>();
        for (int i=0; i<numSets; i++)
        {
            results.add(roll4d6DropLowest());
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

And in your main method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    /*** Rolling the initial sets ***/
    int numSets = 10; // Ten is a placeholder.
                      // This is where you get input from user.

    DiceRoller roller = new DiceRoller();
    List<List<Integer>> diceSets = roller.rollSets(numSets);

    for (List<Integer> diceRolls : diceSets)
    {
        Integer total = sum(diceRolls);
        Integer lowest = Collections.min(diceRolls);
        System.out.println("Total is : " + total + " and lowest is : " + lowest);
    }

    /*** Forcing user to reroll lowest of one set ***/
    int setToRerollIndex = 1; // Placeholder value.
    // Replace with input from user on which set to reroll.
    // Remember to adjust user input - they will probably use a number between 1 
    // and the number of sets, but the List needs an index between 0 and the number of
    // sets - 1. 
    List<Integer> setToReroll = diceSets.get(setToRerollIndex);
    int indexOfLowest = setToReroll.indexOf(Collections.min(setToReroll));
    setToReroll.set(indexOfLowest, roller.rollSingleDie());

    // Selected set has now rerolled the lowest value.
}

public static int sum(List<Integer> list)
{
    int sum= 0; 
    for (int number : list)
        sum = sum + number;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept whichever answer solved your problem.

Comment: You misunderstood my question in the previous post but I guess I'll do like you ask. What I am asking is A) How do I force the user to reroll the lowest of their three highest numbers in the set of their choice. Example: The user rolls a 6, 5, 5, 3. The three is completely ignored and a 5 is printed as the lowest of the three highest. Now assume there are 4 other sets of dice rolls, this set being number 1. I want the user to be able to type in 1 and have that low number (5) be rerolled to a different number. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Polansi It does make sense now. I have updated my answer accordingly. Most of the changes are in your main method, though I also added a `rollSingleDie` method to the `DiceRoller` class. Please let me know if you have any other questions.