# Dungeons and Dragons Dice Roller Reroll

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project2Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numSets = 0;
    System.out.println("How many sets of dice would you like to roll?");
    numSets = kb.nextInt();
    kb.nextLine();

    RollingDice roller = new RollingDice();
    List<List<Integer>> diceSets = roller.rollSets(numSets);

    for (List<Integer> diceRolls : diceSets) {
        Integer total = sum(diceRolls);
        Integer lowest = Collections.min(diceRolls);
        System.out.println("Your roll total is: " + total + " and the lowest roll was a: " + lowest);
    }
    kb.close();
}

public static int sum(List<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int number : list)
        sum = sum + number;
    return sum;
}
}

import java.util.*;

public class RollingDice {
private Random rand;

public RollingDice() {
    this.rand = new Random();
}

public List<Integer> roll4d6DropLowest() {
    List<Integer> retList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        retList.add(rand.nextInt(6) + 1);
    }

    retList.remove(Collections.min(retList));

    return retList;
}

public List<List<Integer>> rollSets(int numSets) {
    List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numSets; i++) {
        results.add(roll4d6DropLowest());
    }
    return results;
}
}
```

Hello Stackoverflow, I am having a small issue with this program. I am trying to make a program to roll four dice and add the three highest rolls together and then print the lowest of those THREE rolls. I made the mistake of of taking the three highest rolls, adding them together, and then printing out the lowest of the four.

How can I fix this issue? I did a lot of googling to figure out how to use lists and collections, but I can't find anything to fix this issue.

Also, how can I make it to where I force the user to select a set and to reroll that set?

Basically what I want to do is have each set assigned to a number (Set 1 is 1, Set 2 is 2, etc.), and then the user types in a number correlating to the number of sets they have, and then the lowest of the three highest rolls is re rolled.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is adding and printing the lowest of the top 3, not all 4. What makes you think it's not?

Comment: @Polansi Can you show the expected input and expected output? If you can do that and be clear with what you want, I can guarantee you will get a nice answer.

Comment: I agree with @Dukeling...  It appears to do exactly what you wanted (not counting features you haven't implemented yet).  `roll4d6DropLowest` returns a `List` of only _three_ items, so `Project2Main.main` can't possibly be doing anything with the (no-longer present) fourth value.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Having trouble with my dungeons and dragons dice roller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748203/having-trouble-with-my-dungeons-and-dragons-dice-roller)

Comment: If you had questions about my answer in your previous post, please comment on the answer and I will try to update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using a List of Lists is a slight case of overbombing here, how about this one:

```
public class Project2Main {
    private static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numSets = 4; //set via Scanner, if wanted

        List<Integer> dices = new ArrayList<Integer>(numSets);
        for (int c = 0; c < numSets; c++) {
            int roll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dices.add(Integer.valueOf(roll));
            System.out.println(roll);
        }

        int[] pair = roll4d6DropLowest(dices);
        System.out.println("lowest of three highest: " + pair[0]);
        System.out.println("sum of 3 highest is: " + pair[1]);    
    }


    /**@param diceRolls Array of dice rolls
     * @return return array of two ints: 
           0: lowest of three highest
           1: sum of three highest */
    private static int[] rollXd6DropLowest(List<Integer> array) {
        int sum = 0;
        int low = 0;

        Collections.sort(array);
        for (int c = (array.size() - 1); c > 0; c--) {
            sum += (int) array.get(c);
            if (c == 1) {
                low = (int) array.get(c);
            }
        }

        int[] pair = { low, sum };
        return pair;
    }

}
```

I admit, returning a `int[]` is not the best of all solutions, but for that little piece of code it should be ok.

Note the initialisation of Random by current time millis to ensure randomness.

The trick is to store the dice rolls in a `List` of `Integers` and sort them according to their "natural ordering" with the help of `Collections`. Highest is topmost.